# SQL Can anyone find an error in my query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Was told by my professor that my output is incorrect for this query that I have to create. Can anyone point to why? Maybe he wants the query done differently? I thought the question was pretty simple. ERD, question, query and output are below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

> - Write a query which displays all trades where more than 50000 shares were traded on the secondary markets.  Please include the trade id, stock symbol, name of the company being traded, stock exchange symbol, number of shares traded, price total and currency symbol.

Output:

```
88  TM  Toyota Motors   NYSE    50300   4099128.08  $
28  TM  Toyota Motors   NYSE    50300   4099128.08  $
88  TYO:6201    Toyota Motors   NYSE    50300   4099128.08  $
28  TYO:6201    Toyota Motors   NYSE    50300   4099128.08  $
71  NYT The New York Times  NYSE    84000   1046892 $
11  NYT The New York Times  NYSE    84000   1046892 $
78  BA  British Airways LSE 72000   14711256    £
18  BA  British Airways LSE 72000   14711256    £


SELECT 
trade.trade_id,
stock_listing.stock_symbol,
company.name company_name,
stock_exchange.symbol AS stock_exchange_symbol,
trade.shares AS number_of_shares_traded,
trade.price_total,
currency.symbol currency_symbol
FROM trade 
JOIN stock_listing 
ON stock_listing.stock_id = trade.stock_id
JOIN company 
ON company.stock_id = trade.stock_id
JOIN stock_exchange 
ON stock_exchange.stock_ex_id = trade.stock_ex_id
JOIN currency
ON currency.currency_id = company.currency_id
WHERE trade.shares > 50000;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you miss the **on the secondary markets** in the assignment? Also, if we can't see sample input data, how can we confirm whether the output is correct or not? See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576)

Comment: What is the meaning of "secondary markets"? The appearance of Toyota twice under different stock symbols suggests to me there may have been more than one stock market involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you have the same Trade IDs on multiple records. That is, it looks like multiple records could be considered a "trade". If that's the case, group by trade ID *first*, then find the count > 50,000.